# css vertical gradient background

Tags: html, css

I want a vertical gradient without using an image. So, I've got this bit of CSS working on Firefox and Chrome, but it isn't working in IE9.

```
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #46a5e5,  #ffffff); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#46A5E5), to(#ffffff)); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(StartColorstr='#46A5E5', EndColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing the up to date prefixed version of the IE filter for IE8 & 9.. though the older still works in IE8

try:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(StartColorstr='#46A5E5', EndColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0); /* IE6/7/8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#46a5e5', endColorstr='#ffffff')"; /* IE8/9 */
zoom: 1;
```

the new version must not be broke (it must stay on one line between the quotes)..

Comment: I tried it all on one line and tried it exactly the way the code looks in the code block, but neither are working on IE9.

Comment: @SquireCD, sorry don't have 9 to check with (no Win7, I love my XP!) however I **think** I've read somewhere but can't find now of course that the order of the rules may be important.. have you tried just with the `-ms-filter` rule - zoom shouldn't be needed - to see if that's working in IE9 and is the background (or background-color) transparent? can you give just an IE9 example that's not working, I can test in 8 others can test in 9.. I'm sure we'll get there for you :) - added: afterthought.. is there any other filters involved here..

Comment: No other filters are involved. I can't test any changes on IE until Monday when I get back to the office (only Linux at home). 

I'm not sure if it helps, but here's my entire CSS file: http://pastebin.com/B2cWuAi9

Class .headBodyFoot is the one I need the gradient for. 

PS: Apologies for the sloppy code. I'm pretty new to CSS.

Comment: It could be something else as I didn't have the HTML. but I took the CSS and just used the gradient code as you had it, and kept the absolute positioning.. and then took a screenshot via browershots, and it appears to work fine in IE9. Here's the page with code used and the IE9 screenshot - http://jsbin.com/asate4/3 - You can test this in your work IE9 on Mon to check against support.. one other thing, when IE9 beta'd it didn't include gradients, not sure how long that lasted tho' ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This article from Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) may be helpful to you when designing for IE with CSS3.

One thing I have learned over the years is it is ok that your website doesn't look exactly the same in each browser, in fact it can be a benefit because I have had situations where the intended design looked fairly different in IE (but still still professional) and some users who preferred that UI would visit with IE instead of the beloved FireFox or Chrome.

Also with IE9, a lot of compatibility to CSS3 and HTML5 has been added so making your site or web app look consistent over all browsers is getting easier!

Just my 2 cents... I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I think height: 1% will solve this problem

```
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #46a5e5,  #ffffff); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#46A5E5), to(#ffffff));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(StartColorstr='#46A5E5', EndColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
height: 1%;
```